# Can't turn off x-ray?

Tags: game-engine, objects, transparency

I've somehow turned x-ray on for all objects in my project, or so it seems.
No matter which object I put in front of the others I will look right through all the layers of objects until I see the last object in the line.

I still see the objects in front, but when there's an object behind the "front-object", then I look through the front-object and see the objects behind it as if they were in front.

If I'm only looking at a single object (in this case a 3D-object), then I don't see the face I'm looking at, but I see the backside and the sides.

When I use the Blender Render, there's no problem, but when I switch to Blender Game Engine and press play, then I look through everything.

[image]

What is the problem?

Here are 4 examples of my problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to deactivate the X-RAY box in each object, I do not know exactly what could be the cause of this because you did not put a reference image and the information is very poor although it basically describes the problem

[image: **X-RAY** Image Reference]
[image: Texture Tab Image reference]
[image: I try to change this]
[image: View inside the game]
[image: IN PLAY GAME]

**change this and correct another part of what is still seen with transparency, you have many errors not related to the question, it is no longer a question of only one answer, it has become a cluster of answers not directly related**

to the animals, uncheck the box backface culling, in the tab Color / Game Settings / backface culling, in the Object / Display / Maximum Draw Type tab, all objects need are in SOLID

[image: animals no need transparency]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90062/discussion-on-answer-by-blender-blackened-cant-turn-off-x-ray).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got an override on transparency material, you most likely duplicated an original material with that property, linked them all up, or are overriding the layer with this material. Delete the material, try a render on a copy file of your original (so you don´t loose data). If this solves the problem, vote me up.

Comment: I have indeed duplicated some of the objects with the ALT + D command (so they keep being identical), but my problem occurs for most of my objects that all have their own material.